# Transactions confirmation

Tags: contract-development, contract-deployment, private-blockchain, testnets, contract-debugging

I am using `geth --dev --ipcpath ~/.ethereum/geth.ipc --minerthreads=5 console` to run privatenet. So i use Etherium wallet to interact with it.

The problem is that i need to do some transfer transactions to confirm other transaction (deploy contract, etc.) bcs mining going on only after some action from Eth. Wallet, is it possible to do it without dealing a lot of transfers? So i need something like:

1. deploy contract transaction
2. wait a moment
3. see 12/12 confirmations of transaction

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking about

Comment: Ty for answer!
I want to transactions generator or something.

Comment: You should be able to transfer 0 ethers to yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Just send zero ethers or call something in console.